# Database is showing i visual studio but not in MSSQL server management

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio

So i want to script my database, as you can see i have it in my visual studio project:
[image]

But in my MSSQL Server Management it's not showing all tabels
[image]

What should i do in this situation? How do i get it in my MSSQL Management so then i can script it?

Comment: Right click Tables and select Refresh.

Comment: Allready done that alot of times.

Comment: My second guess would be that these are in fact different instances of SQL Server then. Localdb vs SQL Express.

Comment: I found the error, i was connectede to RASMUS-PC\SQLEXPRESS and not (LocalDb)\v11.0